# SonarQube in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-pipelines, sonarqube

I am a newbie to DevOps and wanted to learn things by doing.

**What I have done**:

1. I got my code into the Azure Repo (courtesy: Visual Studio Credits) and have a successful build.
2. Now I want to integrate SonarQube for quality gate. In the Azure Devops pipeline, I do find tasks for SonarQube.

**What's the issue**:
I understand that Preparing Analysis Configuration is a necessary step. In this it asks for data points like ServerEndpoint, Project Key and Project Name.
My understanding is it will need a publicly accessible URL in the EndPoint.

Am I getting it right? Is there a way to achieve this integration without any expenditure?

Comment: Are you thinking of the SonarCloud hosted option or the SonarQube open source option installed on your own build machine? As far as I know the only available tasks in Azure DevOps pipelines are for SonarCloud